# apexchart js not working well with Jalali/Perisan calender and not showing labels

Tags: javascript, charts, calendar, timeline, apexcharts

js with moment.js and moment-jalali.js to show a timeline chart in pure js
this is my code to show a chart:

js:

```
    <script>


        // moment.locale('en');


        // moment.locale('fa')
        // moment().format('jYYYY/jM/jD')
        //
        // m = moment('1360/5/26', 'jYYYY/jM/jD') // Parse a Jalaali date
        // m.format('jYYYY/jM/jD [is] YYYY/M/D') // 1360/5/26 is 1981/8/17



        function replaceStrings(str) {
            return str;
            if (str.substring(0, 4) === '1400' || str.substring(0, 4) === '1401') {
                // alert('a')
                if (str.substring(0, 4) === '1400') {
                    // alert('b')
                    return '2022' + str.slice(4, str.length)
                } else {
                    // alert('c')
                    return '2023' + str.slice(4, str.length)
                }
            }
        }


        let id = window.location.href.split('/')[4]
        // alert(id)
        axios.get(url + 'api/chart/' + id).then(res => {
            let attrs = res.data.meta.attributes;
            console.debug(attrs)
            let newAttrs = []
            for (let i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                // alert(moment(replaceStrings(attrs[i].start_date)))
                // alert(((attrs[i].duration)))
                // alert(moment((attrs[i].start_date)).add(attrs[i].duration,'days'))
                newAttrs.push({
                    x: (attrs[i].title),
                    y: [moment(replaceStrings(attrs[i].start_date)).valueOf(), moment(replaceStrings(attrs[i].start_date)).add(attrs[i].duration,'days').valueOf()],
                })
            }
            console.debug(newAttrs)

            var options = {
                series: [
                    {
                        data: newAttrs
                    }
                ],
                title: {
                    align: "right"
                },
                chart: {
                    locales: [{
                        "name": "fa",
                        "options": {
                            "months": [
                                "فروردین",
                                "اردیبهشت",
                                "خرداد",
                                "تیر",
                                "مرداد",
                                "شهریور",
                                "مهر",
                                "آبان",
                                "آذر",
                                "دی",
                                "بهمن",
                                "اسفند"
                            ],
                            "shortMonths": [
                                "فروردین",
                                "اردیبهشت",
                                "خرداد",
                                "تیر",
                                "مرداد",
                                "شهریور",
                                "مهر",
                                "آبان",
                                "آذر",
                                "دی",
                                "بهمن",
                                "اسفند"
                            ],
                            "days": [
                                "یکشنبه",
                                "دوشنبه",
                                "سه شنبه",
                                "چهارشنبه",
                                "پنجشنبه",
                                "جمعه",
                                "شنبه"
                            ],
                            "shortDays": ["ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش"],
                            "toolbar": {
                                "exportToSVG": "دانلود SVG",
                                "exportToPNG": "دانلود PNG",
                                "exportToCSV": "دانلود CSV",
                                "menu": "منو",
                                "selection": "انتخاب",
                                "selectionZoom": "بزرگنمایی انتخابی",
                                "zoomIn": "بزرگنمایی",
                                "zoomOut": "کوچکنمایی",
                                "pan": "پیمایش",
                                "reset": "بازنشانی بزرگنمایی"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ],
                    defaultLocale: 'fa',
                    fontFamily: 'YekanBakh-Regular',
                    height: 500,
                    type: 'rangeBar'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        horizontal: true,
                        distributed: true,
                        dataLabels: {
                            hideOverflowingLabels: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function (val, opts) {
                        // var label = opts.w.globals.labels[opts.dataPointIndex]
                        // var a = moment(val[0])
                        // var b = moment(val[1])
                        // var diff = b.diff(a, 'days')
                        // return label;
                        return '80%'
                    },
                    style: {
                        colors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff']
                    }
                },

                export: {
                    csv: {
                        filename: undefined,
                        columnDelimiter: ',',
                        headerCategory: 'category',
                        headerValue: 'value',
                        dateFormatter(timestamp) {
                            return new Date(timestamp).toDateString()
                        }
                    },
                    svg: {
                        filename: undefined,
                        headerCategory: 'category',
                        headerValue: 'value',
                    },
                    png: {
                        filename: undefined,
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    show: 1,
                    opposite: true

                },
                grid: {
                    row: {
                        colors: ['#f3f4f5', '#fff'],
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                }
            };


            console.debug(options.series)
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart_project"), options);
            chart.render();


        }).catch(err => {
            console.debug(err)
        })

    </script>
```

html:

```
<div class="chart-row two">
            <div class="chart-container-wrapper medium">
                <div class="chart-container">

                    <div class="line-chart">
                        <div id="chart_project"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and here is an example of my data :

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "x": " گود برداری و تخریب",
        "y": [
          -17958684344000,
          -17958597944000
        ],
        "rangeName": "i137bslk"
      },
      {
        "x": " پایدار سازی گود",
        "y": [
          -17958597944000,
          -17958252344000
        ],
        "rangeName": "v68t1wme"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی اسکلت",
        "y": [
          -17958252344000,
          -17957820344000
        ],
        "rangeName": "4091wwtz"
      },
      {
        "x": "آرماتور فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17957820344000,
          -17957388344000
        ],
        "rangeName": "r46n9dfs"
      },
      {
        "x": "قالب بندی فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17957388344000,
          -17957129144000
        ],
        "rangeName": "jgwmc7ba"
      },
      {
        "x": "بتن ریزی فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17957129144000,
          -17956783544000
        ],
        "rangeName": "15p4ud0ji"
      },
      {
        "x": " آرماتور ستون روی فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17956783544000,
          -17956437944000
        ],
        "rangeName": "r1kq0wj2"
      },
      {
        "x": "قالب ستون ها روی فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17956437944000,
          -17956005944000
        ],
        "rangeName": "b0tn9srfj"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی ستون های روی فونداسیون",
        "y": [
          -17955833144000,
          -17955314744000
        ],
        "rangeName": "c4hp4jyo"
      },
      {
        "x": " آرماتور سقف1",
        "y": [
          -17955314744000,
          -17955228344000
        ],
        "rangeName": "k8qln3hf"
      },
      {
        "x": " قالب سقف1",
        "y": [
          -17955228344000,
          -17954882744000
        ],
        "rangeName": "esi38k6yl"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی سقف1",
        "y": [
          -17954882744000,
          -17954450744000
        ],
        "rangeName": "p0y9tazc"
      },
      {
        "x": " آرماتور سقف3",
        "y": [
          -17954450744000,
          -17954191544000
        ],
        "rangeName": "8bg5oxrj"
      },
      {
        "x": " قالب سقف3",
        "y": [
          -17954191544000,
          -17953759544000
        ],
        "rangeName": "umdmtvrth"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی سقف3",
        "y": [
          -17953759544000,
          -17953327544000
        ],
        "rangeName": "wfq54tyx"
      },
      {
        "x": " آرماتور سقف2",
        "y": [
          -17953327544000,
          -17952981944000
        ],
        "rangeName": "qzmev6r9"
      },
      {
        "x": " قالب سقف2",
        "y": [
          -17952981944000,
          -17952549944000
        ],
        "rangeName": "hbomo9q8"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی سقف2",
        "y": [
          -17952549944000,
          -17952204344000
        ],
        "rangeName": "hlcoglikg"
      },
      {
        "x": "آرماتور ستون های خر پشته",
        "y": [
          -17952204344000,
          -17951858744000
        ],
        "rangeName": "f0wkb2z2"
      },
      {
        "x": "قالب ستون های خر پشته",
        "y": [
          -17951858744000,
          -17951513144000
        ],
        "rangeName": "ne0rg1wyh"
      },
      {
        "x": "بتن ریزی ستون خر پشته",
        "y": [
          -17951513144000,
          -17951081144000
        ],
        "rangeName": "y0ys6ylw"
      },
      {
        "x": " آرماتور سقف خر پشته",
        "y": [
          -17951081144000,
          -17950649144000
        ],
        "rangeName": "7kqnhqkt"
      },
      {
        "x": "  قالب بندی سقف خر پشته",
        "y": [
          null,
          null
        ],
        "rangeName": "jwnq9mf"
      },
      {
        "x": " بتن ریزی سقف خر پشته",
        "y": [
          -17950562744000,
          -17950303544000
        ],
        "rangeName": "1irkpuxn"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the result is...:
[image]

And as you can see it is not showing my data label on chart very well
So i tried with gregorian and that worked like a charm. What is the problem of apexchart with Jalali calendar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understand something, if gregorian is working, why don't you using it ?

Comment: I mean just covert Persian date to gregorian date and then display it

Comment: @RaymondShafiee I have to show the dates in Jalali date... I can not use gregorian date

Comment: I know you cannot, I mean just convert the dates to each other to show ! just for showing !